# Debian monitor out of range after install

Tags: debian, boot, startup, monitors, resolution

I've tried adding nomodeset to the boot options from grub at startup (press "e" etc...) but it doesn't work.
I also tried adding vga=795 and although it did work it doesn't get saved plus it's actually really "buggy", the cursor jumps when moving it and it's kind of laggy.
*Nvidia gpu, intel cpu and 8GB of ram.*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it :
Went went with vga=795 anyways then installed nvidia drivers following [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-debian-9-stretch-linux)